# Typescript, with types R and K extends keyof R, how to declare that R[K] is of type string

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have interface Record which looks like

```
interface Record {
  id: string;
  createdBy: string;
  dateCreated: string;
}
```

and interface Result which looks like:

```
interface Result<R extends Record> {
  records: R[];
  referredRercords: { [ref:string]: Record; }
}
```

now, each record of type R contains some key K with a string value that relates to one of the refs in referredRecords.

I want some function to merge these into a coherent object like:

```
mergeRecords<R extends Record, K extends keyof R>(result: Result<R>, refs: [K,string][]) {
  return result.records.map((record) => {

    let refsObj = refs.reduce((acc,[refProp, toProp]) => {
      let key = record[refProp] as string; // ISSUE OCCURS HERE
      let val = result.referredRecords[key]; // OR HERE IF CONVERSION EXCLUDED
      return Object.assign(acc, {[toProp]: val});
    },{});
    return Object.assign(record, refsObj);
  });
}
```

typescript is complaining that the type R[K] does not sufficiently overlap with string for the conversion, and if I exclude the conversion, it complains that type R[K] cannot be used to index type { [ref:string]: Record; }

This works but I dislike it as it seems hacky:

```
let key = record[refProp] as unknown as string;
```

Is there a way I can assure typescript that the type R[K] is indeed a string without doing an unknown conversion beforehand? Or is that just the way to handle this?

Edit:

this also works and I like it somewhat better so I'll go with it unless someone has something better:

```
let key = record[refProp];
let val = (typeof key === 'string') ? result.referredRecords[key] : undefined;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there is already a type in the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1449-L1454) named `Record<K, V>` which stands for an object type whose keys are `K` and whose values are `V`.  I'm going to rename your type to `MyRecord` to distinguish them.   In fact the built-in `Record` type is useful enough that I will probably end up (coincidentally) using it in the answer to this question.

So here's the new code:

```
interface MyRecord {
    id: string;
    createdBy: string;
    dateCreated: string;
}

interface Result<R extends MyRecord> {
    records: R[];
    referredRecords: { [ref: string]: MyRecord; }
}

function mergeRecords<R extends MyRecord, K extends keyof R>(
    result: Result<R>, refs: [K, string][]
) {
    return result.records.map((record) => {

        let refsObj = refs.reduce((acc, [refProp, toProp]) => {
            let key: string = record[refProp]; // error, not a string 
            let val = result.referredRecords[key]; 
            return Object.assign(acc, { [toProp]: val });
        }, {});
        return Object.assign(record, refsObj);
    });
}
```

Your main problem is that you have *assumed* that `R[K]` will be a `string`, but you haven't told the compiler that.  So the current definition of `mergeRecords()` will be happy to accept this:

```
interface Oops extends MyRecord {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}
declare const result: Result<Oops>;
mergeRecords(result, [["foo", "bar"]]); // okay, but it shouldn't accept "foo"!
mergeRecords(result, [["bar", "baz"]]); // okay
```

Oops.

---

Ideally you should constrain the `R` (and maybe `K`) types to let the compiler know what's going on.  Here's one way to do it:

```
// return the keys from T whose property types match the type V
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { 
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never 
}[keyof T];

function mergeRecords<
    R extends MyRecord & Record<K, string>, 
    K extends KeysMatching<R, string>
>(
    result: Result<R>, refs: [K, string][]
) {
    return result.records.map((record) => {

        let refsObj = refs.reduce((acc, [refProp, toProp]) => {
            let key: string = record[refProp]; // no error now
            let val = result.referredRecords[key];
            return Object.assign(acc, { [toProp]: val });
        }, {});
        return Object.assign(record, refsObj);
    });
}
```

Now `R` is constrained not only to `MyRecord`, but also to `Record<K, string>`, so any property at key `K` must have type `string`.  This is enough to silence that error in the `let key: string = ...` statement.  Furthermore, `K` is (redundantly to us but not to the compiler) constrained to `KeysMatching<T, string>`, meaning the subset of keys of `T` whose properties are `string` values.  This helps with IntelliSense when calling the function.

EDIT: How `KeysMatching<T, V>` works... there are different ways to do this, but the way above is to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to iterate over the keys `K` of `T` and make a new type whose properties are a function of the property of `T`. The [`-?` modifier](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) makes each property of the new type required, even if the property in `T` is optional.  Specifically I used a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to see if `T[K]` matches `V`.  If so, it returns `K`; if not, it returns `never`.  So if we did `KeysMatching<{a: string, b: number}, string>`, the mapped type becomes `{a: "a", b: never}`.  Then, we [index into](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) that mapped type with `keyof T` to get the value types.  So `{a: "a", b: never}["a" | "b"]` becomes `"a" | never` which is just `"a"`.

Let's see it in action now:

```
interface Oops extends MyRecord {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}
declare const result: Result<Oops>;
mergeRecords(result, [["foo", "bar"]]); // error on "foo"
mergeRecords(result, [["bar", "baz"]]); // okay
```

Now the first call fails as desired, since the property at `"foo"` is not a `string`, while the second call still succeeds because the property at `"bar"` is fine.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks a lot, very thorough, will test and accept ASAP.  If this works I'll likely be asking another question about typing the return value if you think you could help out with that as well.

Comment: I get most of this and it definitely works, would you be able to explain the KeysMatching type a bit more? specifically what the '-?' part means and the [keyof T] at the end?